# D3-tip tooltips are getting stuck after zoom-in in dc.js chart

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, dc.js

I have create a stacked bar chart having zoom & brush features with range selector sub-chart using dc.js.

[image: Image chart with brush,zoom feature & tool-tips]

There is tool-tip on the top chart which shows on mouse hover using d3-tip. After doing brush or zooming the tool-tips mostly gets stuck & does not get hide.

I am adding tool-tip using below code.

```
    .on("pretransition",(c)=> {
      this.addTooltip();//calling tool-tip method
    })
```

And using below logic to show & hide the tool-tip on different events

```
      this.mainChart.selectAll('rect').call(tip)
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
            .on('wheel',tip.hide)
            .on('mousezoomin.zoom',tip.hide)
            .on('mousezoomout.zoom',tip.hide)
            .on('mousewheel.zoom', tip.hide)
            .on('mouseup', tip.hide)
            .on('mousewheel', tip.hide)
            .on('mousezoomout', tip.hide)
            .on('mousezoomin', tip.hide)
            .on('mousemove', (d) => {  //...});
```

Let me know how to solve tool-tip stuck issue after zooming or brushing of chart.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try doing `.call(tip)` only once at initialization, not every `pretransition`? I don't think d3-tip is meant to be initialized more than once.

Comment: Gordon, now calling `this.addTooltip();` in `postRender` event did work but its not working for those bars which are re-appearing in the window after zoom-in & zoom-out. And trying again calling inside `zoomed` event causing the same issue again.

Comment: Thank you Gordon !! , your suggestion did work for me.